# NAT on TCP connections

Tags: networking

When we establish a TCP connection from PC1 to Server and send data through this connection, how does the Router know to which of the two PCs (PC1 and PC2) should it communicate on the way back from Server to PC1?

And

How does ping (ICMP) know to which internal node it should send the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NAT (Network Address Translation) is stateful. It creates a translation table that has the layer-3 and layer-4 protocols and addresses. By looking up the return traffic addresses in the translation table, the NAT process can determine which inside addresses should be placed in the packet.

**Edit:**

Per the edit to your question, asking about ICMP (it is very bad form to change the question in order to ask a different question because it can invalidate the perfectly acceptable answers already given):

It is all the same as TCP or UDP. NAT creates a state table that is dynamically built as traffic passes from inside to outside. NAPT will allow you to overload a single IP address with traffic from multiple inside addresses, and it will translate the return traffic by looking up where to send it in its state table.

With NAPT, besides looking at and translating the IP address, NAPT looks at the layer-4 protocol (TCP, UDP, ICMP) and translates the layer-4 addresses (TCP or UDP port numbers or ICMP identifies), too, storing the translations in its translation table. When return traffic is destined to a particular layer-3 and layer-4 address combination, from a particular layer-3 and layer-4 address combination, the NAPT process finds that in its translation table, and it can see where to send the traffic on the inside.

NAT is very resource intensive, and it breaks the IP paradigm of end-to-end connectivity, where every host is uniquely identified by its own IP address, which is why it is called a kludge (or worse). NAT was developed to extend the life of IPv4 until IPv6, with its nearly unlimited addressing, can become ubiquitous.

[*RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2663):

> 4.1.2. Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)
>
> NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also
> translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP
> query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number
> of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a
> single external address. NAPT allows a set of hosts to share a single
> external address. Note that NAPT can be combined with Basic NAT so
> that a pool of external addresses are used in conjunction with port
> translation.
>
> For packets outbound from the private network, NAPT would translate
> the source IP address, source transport identifier and related fields
> such as IP, TCP, UDP and ICMP header checksums. Transport identifier
> can be one of TCP/UDP port or ICMP query ID. For inbound packets, the
> destination IP address, destination transport identifier and the IP
> and transport header checksums are translated.
>
> A NAPT router in figure 2 may be configured to translate sessions
> originated from N-Pri into a single external address, say Addr-i.
>
> Very often, the external interface address Addr-Nx of NAPT router is
> used as the address to map N-Pri to.

Comment: how NAT router will come to know the layer4 port number? It breaks the IP packet?

Answer (score 1):

There is a large pool of resources describing NAT (Network Address Translation), which is available if you search "nat explained". A great resource is What is [NAT and how it work tutorial](http://www.internet-computer-security.com/Firewall/NAT.html).

The most important detail is that commonly we use NAPT (commonly used as PAT - Port Address Translation) (Network Address and Port Translation), alongside NAT.

When a device needs to use the Internet, it must open a local (source port) and send the IP request to the other end. For example, a notepad with source IP address 192.168.1.2 needs to communicate with a web server at 216.58.212.35.

It fires up random source port 1234 and requests information from target port 80 (HTTP - Web page).

This goes through the networks NAT device, which stores the information 192.168.1.2/1234 with the next information that it computes, and sends the request as 46.103.93.105 (its own IP public IP) and a new source port, for example 2345.

The web server responds to the NAT device, which in turn finds the correlated information (source port 2345 targets 192.168.1.2/1234). The notepad receives the information and displays it to the user.

Comment: PAT is actually a misnomer. _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2, Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663)_ describes it: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address. NAPT allows a set of hosts to share a single external address._"

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: How does ping (ICMP) know to which internal node it should send the answer?

Comment: I think it is adequately addressed in the accepted answer, it is not different as the example I gave, in that the NAT device basically holds more information to identify the packet.

Answer (score -1):

The router adds information to the request header sent to the server that allows it to look up the sender when the reply is received.  This is usually accomplished by using a table stored in the router's memory that maps the PC's   address to the token added to the header.

Comment: NAT has nothing to do with layer-2 (MAC) addresses. NAT translates layer-3 (IP) and, possibly, layer-4 (TCP and UDP) addresses (ports) if it is NAPT.